# TSQL Column Constraints

Tags: t-sql

So, I have a table with three columns, and I want to be able to say, that if column 1 has "A" in it, then Column 2 MUST be "B" and Column 3 MUST be "C"

So the table would be like...

"A" "B" "C"

"D" "E" "F"

"G" "H" "I"

**The first column should determine the value of the other two**

I'd just google this, but I'm not sure what it's called exactly.

I really hope that makes sense.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Management Studio

**EDIT**

Apparently my question is very confusing, so I'll try and explain more:
Let's say we have a table of animals and what they eat.

We have a giraffe, a fish, and a lion

A giraffe eats leaves

A fish eats water

A lion eats meat

(ignore the inaccuracy of any of that).

When I fill in a new Giraffe into the table I want to GUARANTEE that ONLY leaves can be put into the other column. An animal should ONLY be able to eat the food it is assigned. How do I ensure that?

Comment: Why do you need 3 different columns if they are constrained to be identical?

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean it to be the same data. It will all be different. Ill edit it.

Comment: @Johannes: while you're there, consider what else may be wrong... You have completely changed the question. Like, will this always be char(1) in the range A-X? Will you only populate column1?

Comment: @Johannes - Even with the amended version the basic question still stands. What is the purpose of cols 2 and 3 if they can be computed from col 1? And are you aware of computed columns?

Comment: What if an animal eats more then one food? Omnivores?

Comment: An animal should only be able to eat one type of food ONLY. This is just an example I pulled out of thin air, don't look too far into it :p

Comment: Seems like you are talking about denormalising. Do you have another table that contains a matrix of animals and food types? If so why not join onto that rather than storing the same fact repeatedly with risk of anomalies etc.

Comment: Let me add a comment in here: If the next column is always the previous "column+1" (whatever that means in the context of the data and your app) you can definitely enforce it yourself by only asking for the first value only!!! What's the point in asking a user to enter data beyond the first column?  Better yet, don't even store the next 2 columns, simply create a view that returns the first column from the table and the next two columns you calculate on your own.

Comment: @Johannes: what problem are you trying to solve? You have change the question **twice** now. Give us full, correct information or delete this question. I started a solution for A, B C and changed it for your invented food/animal scenario. That's wasting my time

Comment: I just saw the clarification from Johannes... what you are looking for is referential integrity and it's simple to do if you set 2 tables: One for animal (animal_id, animal_name) and one for animal_food(animal_id,food_id,food_name) you then tell your animal_food table that animal_id is a foreign key and comes from table animal and you make the PRIMARY key of that table the  combination of (animal_id,food_id) this will ensure a 1:1 rel between animal and animal_food.

Comment: Proper [sample code](http://sscce.org/) (here, SQL statements) is more useful than any ad hoc schema and sample data format. Please use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT ... VALUES` for samples. Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a constraint: just proper design. There are too many permutations of food and animals to have as code: for a new animal of food, you'd need to change your constraints. And what if an animal eats more than one food?

I'd add a

- food table
- a link (many-many) table between food and animals

The link table is loaded with what each animal can eat. The food info is not part of the animal table.